# How to show the value of the value of the variable in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off  
set a=b  
set b=c  
echo %%a%%
```

It doesn't work, it only shows %b%. I want to make it to show `c`. I don't know why if it is only the version of the OS (Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1) or it really wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need another parsing layer: Either:

```
call echo %%%a%%%
```

in batchfiles, or on command line:

```
call echo %%a%%
```

or using [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set a=b
set b=c
echo !%a%!
```